# Tangent space for the differentiable manifold $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

Since $S^1$ is a compact 1-dimensional regular submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (it's $S^1 = f^{-1}(1)$ for $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given as $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$), we can find the tangent space for $S^1$ in (1,0) as $$T_{(1,0)}(S^1) = Ker(d(f)_{(1,0)}).$$ Intuitively $T_{(1,0)}(S^1)$ is the plane $\{(1,y): y \in \mathbb{R}\}.$

But we get $$Ker(d(f)_{(1,0)}) = Ker((2x,2y)_{(1,0)}) = Ker((2,0)) = \{(0,y) : y \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$

What it is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are calculating the tangent space as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  So, it passes through the origin.  You can then translate it to the point $(1, 0)$.

Comment: Your result is a subspace of tangent space $T_{(1,0)}R^2$. Nothing wrong with your calculation. The result represent the components of tangent vectors. That is the elements of the kernel should be in the form $0 \partial_x + s\partial_y$ for $s\in R$. Which is exactly what you wanted (up to the identification).

Comment: @KelvinLois: This looks like essentially an answer. Would you mind writing it up so that we can get this question off the Unanswered queue?